# How can I modify/control the HTML output of my Module?

Tags: mysql, module, module-params

I'm developing a Joomla 3.x.x module which connects through to a components table in the database.

I have got the following code in the helper.php which outputs the variables successfully:

```
public static function renderElement($table_name, $field_name, $field_value) {
    $result = '';

    switch ($table_name) {

    case '#__competition_data':
    switch($field_name){
    case 'id':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'title':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'introtext':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'maintext':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'image':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'question':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'correct_answer':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'false_answer1':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'false_answer2':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'closing_date':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'terms':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'additional_info':
    $result = $field_value;
    break;
    case 'created_by':
    $user = JFactory::getUser($field_value);
    $result = $user->name;
    break;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The frontend php file then outputs the above using the following:

```
<div class="span8"><?php echo ModCompetitionHelper::renderElement($params->get('item_table'), $field_name, $field_value); ?></div>
```

But they are outputted as different DIV's, one of them is an image so I want to be able to control what they are outputted as.

Ideally something along the lines of:

```
case '#__competition_data':
    switch($field_name){
    case 'id':
    $result = $field_value_id;
    break;
```

I can't work out how to do it though, any ideas please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case 'image':
    $result = '<img src="' . $field_value . '" />';
    break;
```

How about this for example?